# Docker Compose: custom container names don't work with docker-compose down

Tags: docker, file, docker-compose, config, docker-container

I wish to use custom container names in `docker-compose.yml`. I used the clause `container_name` like the example below:

```yaml
...
services:
    mysql:
        image: "mysql"
        container_name: mysql
...
```

When I execute `docker-compose up -d` It works fine, all the containers in `.yml` starts and set all up.

But when I execute `docker-compose down`, the project name defaults to my project folder name and it can't locate the custom named containers I wrote in `docker-compose.yml`.

How can I use `docker-container down` with custom container names?

Comment: Could you add the error you get when you try to `docker-compose down`?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan Yesterday I tested a lot and it was catching the project folder name and throwing the error, now I tested and its working. docker-compose caches the project name?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can't really say anything without seeing the actual error. Sorry!

Comment: The error is basically pointing like "my_folder_container container not found." and "network my_folder_network not found". Thats all I can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eranga Heshan's comment I retested and the command run successfully. It was not a error of docker compose error as I inquired and thought it was.